# TensorFlow Lite: RuntimeError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am using TensorFlow version: 2.3.0 and Python3. I am experimenting in Quantizing a pruned and trained Conv-2 CNN model. The model architecture is: conv -> conv -> max pool -> dense -> dense -> output for CIFAR-10. You can see the Jupyter-notebook [here](https://github.com/arjun-majumdar/Lottery_Ticket_Hypothesis-TensorFlow_2/blob/master/Conv2_Quantization_Experiments.ipynb).

The pruned and trained model is stored in the variable "pruned_model". Steps used for quantization are as follows:

```
# Save the entire pruned and saved model-
pruned_model.save("Conv2_Pruned")

# Dynamic range quantization-
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("Conv2_Pruned")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()


def representative_data_gen():
    # for inp_val, _ in test_dataset.take(1):
    for inp_val, _ in test_dataset.batch(1).take(100):
        # Model has only one input so each data point has one element.
        yield [inp_val]


import pathlib

# Quantization  using integer with float fallback-
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("Conv2_Pruned")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen

converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]

# DON'T USE THE FOLLOWING 2 LINES-
# converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
# converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8

tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
```

This last line gives the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 14 # converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
> 15
> ---> 16 tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py
> in convert(self)    1074         Invalid quantization parameters.
> 1075     """
> -> 1076     return super(TFLiteConverterV2, self).convert()    1077     1078
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py
> in convert(self)
> 897           graph=frozen_func.graph)
> 898
> --> 899     return super(TFLiteFrozenGraphConverterV2,
> 900                  self).convert(graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors)
> 901
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py
> in convert(self, graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors)
> 636         self.inference_input_type, self.inference_output_type)
> 637     if calibrate_and_quantize:
> --> 638       result = self._calibrate_quantize_model(result, **flags)
> 639
> 640     if self._experimental_sparsify_model:
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py
> in _calibrate_quantize_model(self, result, inference_input_type,
> inference_output_type, activations_type, allow_float)
> 448       return _mlir_quantize(calibrated)
> 449     else:
> --> 450       return calibrate_quantize.calibrate_and_quantize(
> 451           self.representative_dataset.input_gen, inference_input_type,
> 452           inference_output_type, allow_float, activations_type)
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\optimize\calibrator.py
> in calibrate_and_quantize(self, dataset_gen, input_type, output_type,
> allow_float, activations_type, resize_input)
> 89         initialized = True
> 90         if resize_input:
> ---> 91           self._calibrator.Prepare([list(s.shape) for s in sample])
> 92         else:
> 93           self._calibrator.Prepare()
>
> RuntimeError: tensorflow/lite/kernels/conv.cc:313 input->dims->size !=
> 4 (5 != 4)Node number 0 (CONV_2D) failed to prepare.

I first experimented with LeNet-300-100 using MNIST and this error wasn't existing for it.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran the colab. The input tensor accepts 4D data, but the inp_val is 5D. Fixing each inp_val to have a single input tensor value should work.

Comment: Can you provide a short code snippet for this?

Comment: something similar to return np.array(inp_val).reshape(60, 32, 32, 3) depends on the actual input tensor shape instead of return [inp_vap]. when you print the shape of inp_val, it's an array with 5 values.